# WPF binding ObservableCollection<string> to ItemsControl not working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, observablecollection, itemscontrol

I have some string property that content need to be parsed, and displayed in separate controls. Let's say there are e-mails and urls separated by whitespaces. Displaying emails works fine, but urls don't. Here's code:

XAML file:

```xml
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBox Name="EmailTextBox"
                     Text="{Binding ElementName=candidatePersonalDataViewControl, Mode=OneWay, Path=Candidate.Email, Converter={StaticResource emailConverter}}"/>

            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=candidatePersonalDataViewControl, Mode=OneWay, Path=UrlsProperty}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock
                            Margin="0,0,0,0"
                            Padding="5,2,5,2"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Path=/}" 
                                       Click="EmailAsWWW_Click">
                                <Run Text="{Binding Path=/}" />
                            </Hyperlink>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

C# file:

```cs
    private static readonly DependencyProperty CandidateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Candidate", typeof(Candidate), typeof(CandidatePersonalDataViewControl));
    public Candidate Candidate
    {
        get { return (Candidate)GetValue(CandidateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CandidateProperty, value); }
    }

    public CandidatePersonalDataViewControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        UrlsProperty = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> UrlsProperty
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    private void Grid_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Candidate == null)
            return;
        if (Candidate.Email == null)
            return;


        EmailPropertyToEmailsConverter emailConverter = new EmailPropertyToEmailsConverter();
        bool emails = (emailConverter.Convert(Candidate.Email, typeof(string), null, null) as string) != null;
        this.EmailTextBox.Visibility = emails ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;

        EmailPropertyToUrlListConverter urlConverter = new EmailPropertyToUrlListConverter();
        IList<string> urls = urlConverter.Convert(Candidate.Email, typeof(string), null, null) as IList<string>;
        UrlsProperty.Clear();
        if (urls != null)
            foreach (string url in urls)
                UrlsProperty.Add(url);
    }
```

I have debugged Grid_LayoutUpdated and it works fine. It's fired whenever it's needed and UrlsCollection contains desired data. As I said, EmailTextBox displays the data, but ItemsControl is empty all the time. What is more interesing, removing "Path=/" from Hyperlink bindings raises an XAML Parse exception. I've run out of ideas... 
I have read some topics, but none was helpful

[wpf ItemsControl binding problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159128/wpf-itemscontrol-binding-problem)

[WPF Binding Path=/ not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784377/wpf-binding-path-not-working)

[WPF - bind a listbox to a list<string> - what am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488840/wpf-bind-a-listbox-to-a-liststring-what-am-i-doing-wrong)

[How do you bind ObservableCollections to ItemsSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303557/how-do-you-bind-observablecollections-to-itemssource)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Path=/` binds to the *current item **of a collection*** not the *current item that is being templated*, usually said current item is the one that is selected (see [`IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem.aspx)). Your `DataContext` is a string and not a collection, hence trying to bind to a current item via `/` will fail (see [binding errors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx)).

To bind to the *current item that is being templated* you need to bind directly to the `DataContext` which can be done via `{Binding}` or `{Binding .}`/`{Binding Path=.}` (if the property requires a `Binding.Path` choose one of the latter).

Answer (score 1):

your hyperlink control need an Uri for the NavigateUri property, but you just bind to a string.

one way to achieve what you want is using a converter for your NavigateUri Binding

```
<Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource YourStringToUriConverterGoesHere}}" Click="EmailAsWWW_Click">
  <Run Text="{Binding}" />
</Hyperlink>
```

an other way is change the collection

```
public ObservableCollection<MyUrlWrapper> UrlsProperty
{
    get;
    private set;
}

public class MyUrlWrapper
{
    public string Url {get;set;}
    public Uri MyUri {get{return new Uri(this.Url);}}
}

<Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Path=MyUri}" Click="EmailAsWWW_Click">
  <Run Text="{Binding Path=Url}" />
</Hyperlink>
```

Comment: Checked and didn't help :( I believe it's not a problem. I've used Hyerplink without converter before, and it works fine. Thanks for reply anyway.

Comment: pls try: <DataTemplate><TextBlock Text="{Binding}" /></DataTemplate> just to see that the collection is not empty and the binding is right.

Comment: one more thing- are the any binding error in your output window? you can also check for binding errors with Snoop.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding}" Click="EmailAsWWW_Click">
    <Run Text="{Binding}" />
</Hyperlink>
```

Comment: What is more interesing, removing "Path=/" from Hyperlink bindings raises an XAML Parse exception.